# Android Studio not restarting

Tags: android-studio

I am using android studio version 4, the indexing of project takes longer time, so solution i tried was to `Invalidate caches and Restart`, but the problem is that android studio is not restarting waited for more than hours , i also tried to open it by clicking icon (application exe) , still it doesn't open, i have to restart the system again to open android studio.

OS : Windows 10

Android studio version :4.0.1

Any suggestions would be appreciated, because every time i have to restart the system after `Invalidate caches and Restart`.